# Delphi Rio DUNITX in Gitlab CI for Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, delphi, dunitx

I have set up a gitlab CI runner that compiles my DUNITX unit tests for Linux, OSX and Windows and runs them on three machines. I do not use PAClient but upoad the compiled unit test application to the machine and run it there. This works perfect and having developed a taste for it I would like to expand that for the foundation classes I use on Android and IOS. Here I come across several hurdles:

1. DUNITX does not compile for these platforms although I read a lot about using DUNITX at least on Android. Perhaps I am missing something? On Android it complains "DUnitx.Linux.Console.pas" not found although the file exists and is in path.
2. How can I upload/transfer the compiled packages to IOS and Android. In the Android world ADB should make this possible but I have no Idea how to do that in IOS.

Any Help is very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a project that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I just need to use the dunitx wizard, create a default project add the Android platform and compile.

Comment: Meanwhile I could compile for Android by dropping the console logger but the app hangs on android on creation of the runner and no tests are executed.

Comment: My current approach is writing a single form application and reproducing the test cases for mobile, feeding the results into a memo. This is not too much errort as the common testcases between desktop and mobile are not too much. Still open for me: How to start on IOS and how to gather the results.

Comment: You could try using the DUNitX.Loggers.MobileGUI unit and create an instance of TMobileGUITestRunner

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Infortunately not but I do not need it currently.